# How to make html menu for JavaScript call?

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I made online drawing for electronics layout editing and used html form select tag to pick the component to draw.

```
<label>Electronics component - <select id="chose">
        <option value="resistor">Resistor</option>
        <option value="pot">Potentiomenter</option>
        <option value="cap">Capacitor</option>
```

....and so on

As the script growing, I need a html menu for easier component choosing, but I can't implement the `getelementsbytagname('li')` to call for chosen component.

You can see it at: http://www.3lectronics.com/electronics-layout/Atarado-Draw1.html and figure what I'm talking about. I already browsed similar issues and didn't find the appropriate answer.

Please help.

Comment: Can you paste the script here please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a helpful [resource at W3C](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp) to see what events are available from which HTML elements, and to figure out what to do in the JS [another resource](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_select.asp) that tells you what properties JavaScript can access in which HTML elements.

As for the code. You'll want to attach a `JS` listener to the `onchange` event of the select element.

The HTML

```
<select id="chose" onchange="dropDownSelectionChange(this.form.chose)">
```

The JavaScript

```
function dropDownSelectionChange(dropdown)
{
    // the selected index in the dropdown
    var idx  = dropdown.selectedIndex
    // the selected value in the dropdown
    var value = dropdown.options[idx].value

    // do some work here.
}
```

Happy coding.

**update**

HTML

```
<ul>
  <li id="one" onclick="doStuff(this);">one</li>
</ul>
```

JS

```
function doStuff (elem) {
  alert(elem.id);
  return false;
}
```

if you want you can wrap the text in the LI element in an html anchor to get it highlighted as a link or do this with css whichever way you prefer.

Comment: thank you for your answer, but I want to change dropdown form menu and make UL/LI menu in html to choose electronics component like link in HTML, and put some IMG...

Comment: @Alex: I don't quite see the problem. You still just attach the JS function to the HTML element. See above.

Comment: Oh, sorry now it's clear to me. I'm code noob and didn't get it at first. Thank you for help!